# Installing OSVR on Linux - Setting binary directory

Tags: linux, cmake, debian, osvr

I am currently trying to install [OSVR-Core](https://github.com/OSVR/OSVR-Core) on my Debian 9.1 system. I installed all the prerequisites and followed [this](https://github.com/OSVR/OSVR-Docs/blob/master/Getting-Started/Installing/Linux-Build-Instructions.md) tutorial. Now I am stuck at making the project. I created a build-directory and tried running

`cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local/stow/libfunctionality" ~/src/OSVR-Core`

but I get the error, that my binary directory should be different from my source directory. My source directory (with the make-files) should be ~/src/OSVR-Core and since I am in ~/src/OSVR-Core/build, I thought this was enough.

How (and where) do I change the location of the binary directory? I tried the command line option `-D CMAKE_BINARY_DIR= "path/to/OSVR-Core/build` but that did not work. I read online, that you should not set the Binary directory manually, but that it is created/calculated.

This is the CMakeError.log file:

```
    Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/lenala/src/OSVR-Core/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_42e59/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_42e59.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_42e59.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/lenala/src/OSVR-Core/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_42e59.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_42e59.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /home/lenala/src/OSVR-Core/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_42e59
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_42e59.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTC_42e59.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTC_42e59 -rdynamic 
CMakeFiles/cmTC_42e59.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTC_42e59.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_42e59' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTC_42e59] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lenala/src/OSVR-Core/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_42e59/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_42e59/fast] Error 2

File /home/lenala/src/OSVR-Core/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output: Change Dir: /home/lenala/src/OSVR-Core/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_f2984/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_f2984.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_f2984.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/lenala/src/OSVR-Core/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f2984.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_f2984.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_f2984
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_f2984.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTC_f2984.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_f2984 -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmTC_f2984.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_f2984' failed
make[1]: *** [cmTC_f2984] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lenala/src/OSVR-Core/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_f2984/fast' failed
make: *** [cmTC_f2984/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: That looks like an error about pthreads, not about the binary directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. I reinstalled [libfunctionality](https://github.com/OSVR/libfunctionality) in my *~/src* directory. Then I removed the github repository of OSVR-core and cloned it again. After that it worked, using:

`$ cmake .. -DJSONCPP_WITH_CMAKE_PACKAGE=ON -DJSONCPP_LIB_BUILD_SHARED=OFF -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fPIC
$ make`

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the

`cmake .. -DJSONCPP_WITH_CMAKE_PACKAGE=ON -DJSONCPP_LIB_BUILD_SHARED=OFF -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-fPIC`

since that's what the tutorial says to use to build the project and that the CMakaList.txt will handle all the paths.

Comment: I still get the same error message when using this.